# Websocket on upgrade socket.write

Tags: node.js, websocket, ws

Im using **ws** client to manage websocket connection. Every thing works fine expect socket.write. There is example here https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#client-authentication

```
server.on('upgrade', function upgrade(request, socket, head) {
  // This function is not defined on purpose. Implement it with your own logic.
  authenticate(request, function next(err, client) {
    if (err || !client) {
      socket.write('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized\r\n\r\n');
      socket.destroy();
      return;
    }

    wss.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, function done(ws) {
      wss.emit('connection', ws, request, client);
    });
  });
});
```

What this line `socket.write('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized\r\n\r\n');` exactly should do? How I will receive it on client side? Because now on client side I have an error callback

```
ws.onerror = (event) => {
  console.log(event)
}
```

It is called, but there is no ''HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized\r\n\r\n' in **event**

Comment: @Marc Thank you. I understand that. Where and how can I get it on client side, thats my question.

Comment: @Marc Ok. How can I check it? No response in Dev console.